# Debugging remote application in Eclipse using Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat8

I'm trying to debug a remote Java application in Eclipse that runs on a Tomcat server. I keep running into one of two errors depending on how my debugging is set up. I am not using any proxy or VPN, all the code is run on my own machine.

I cannot show a lot of code, but I can describe exactly the steps I took:

First, I changed the code in `startup.bat` located in the bin directory of Tomcat:

`call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%` changed to `call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`

Just above this line, I added the following JVM parameters. I have no idea what parameters they are supposed to be nor do I know if this is the right place to put them, but I just followed one example:

`set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

On Eclipse, here is the port configuration I have for the server:

```
Tomcat Admin port: 8005
HTTP/1.1: 8080
SSL: 8443
AJP/1.3: 8009
```

After making sure the server is running without errors, I then opened run->debug configuration->remote Java application and set these parameters, and then hit Debug:

```
Host:localhost
Port:8000
```

Doing so results with a "connection refused" error. When I change the port number in the debug configuration to 8080 or 8005, then the startup waits for 20 seconds, and then returns a "connection timeout" error. When I increase the timeout to 3 minutes, then the startup waits for 3 minutes, and then returns a "connection timeout" error. Changing the "address" in the JVM settings does not seem to make any difference, no matter if its set to 8005 or 8080.

Do you have any suggestions of things I could try to look into?
Thanks,
Nathan

[image: Added a screenshot to show what I am doing]

Comment: How do you start Tomcat? Implicitly (from Eclipse) oder explicitly (by manually launching start.bat)?

Comment: I start it from eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont have to modify anything coming out of the box.
if you want to start your tomcat in debug mode then from the bin folder run 
"./catalina.sh jpda start" if running in mac or linux or run "catalina jpda start",

this will start tomcat in debug mode and then you can try connecting your debugger to port 8000.

Comment: I'm running on Windows

Comment: In that case you can execute catalina.bat instead of catalina.sh steps remains same

Comment: Executing catalina.bat causes it to run in debug mode listening to port 8000? Or are you saying I have to execute ```catalina.bat jpda start``` in cmd? And then in Eclipse, I just debug on that port and host names and it will pick up breakpoints and such?

Comment: just run catalina.bat from bin folder and attached remote debugger from eclipse

Comment: It seems like when I run `catalina.bat` from the bin folder, and then hit "debug" in eclipse debug configuration window, it seems like nothing happens at all. I don't see any feedback at all that indicates it's debugging. When I try to hit "debug" a second time at that point, I get a "connection refused" error

Comment: did you try putting break point on your code and execute, please notice that if your eclipse is attached to debug then break point sign changes a little bit.also you can look into thread tab at the bottom, it should show you thread stack

Comment: I cannot find any window called "thread" but when I added windows for registers, variables, and breakpoints none of these change at all regardless when I'm debugging or not. The blue dot in eclipse for the breakpoint never changes either. It is port 8000 right? Does this mean the breakpoint is never hit, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: would you be able to provide screenshot for your steps?

Comment: Attached an image

Comment: looking at the screenshot it tells me that your server is running in debug mode and eclipse connected to your tomcat server for sure. probably you are not hitting code which should pass through your breakpoint

Comment: I think you were right, I got it to hit a breakpoint now. However, the blue dot in the source code has remained unchanged. Instead, a new tab appeared in Eclipse that reads "Class file editor - source not found. You can change the source attachment by clicking the Change Attached Source below:" When I click that button I select the folder my source code is located in, but this does not change the result. What do you think? Do you need me to attach another screenshot?

Comment: it will ask you to attache source code only if you are stepping inside class which is a third party library else it should just step over on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202807/discussion-between-jigar-gajjar-and-nathan-goedeke).